# Update não funciona na base de dados

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tenho o seguinte código e quando dou submit ele não faz update a NADA na base de dados.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tests WHERE ID = :ID";
$result = $db->prepare($query);
$result->execute(array(':ID' => $_REQUEST['ID']) );
if ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { 
?>


 <br />
 <br />

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post"> 

  <input id="Game" type="text" name="Name" value="<?php echo $row['Name]; ?>" required />



 <br />

 <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>" />
 <input type="Submit" name="Submit" value="Salvar alterações" />
</form>

<? 
 } 
 elseif (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
 $ID = $_POST['ID']; 

 $Name = $_POST['Name'];

 $queryupdate = "UPDATE tests SET Name = :Name WHERE ID= :ID";  
 $q = $db->prepare($queryupdate);
 $q->execute(array(":ID" => $ID, ":Name" => $Name));
 header ('Location: edit.php');}
```

Comment: Pelo que entendi do seu código, seu `if` sempre retornará `true` se houverem dados na tabela `tests` e nunca entrará no `elseif` para executar `update`, tente trocar esse `elseif` por somente `if` e faça o `submit` do `form` novamente.

Comment: Funcionou, pode dizer-me o porque de nao dar com o `elseif`? Responda com isto e eu dou um certo na sua resposta para ter mais pontos !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema está no primeiro `if` que sempre retornará `true` se houverem dados na tabela `tests` e nunca entrará no `elseif` para executar `update`, tente trocar esse `elseif` por somente `if` e faça o `submit` do `form` novamente. Veja abaixo:

Simplificando seu código para melhor entendimento.

```
/* Você faz um select na tabela e testa
 * se houverem dados da tabela, então faça
 */
if ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
  ...
} 
//Aqui você testa senão houverem dados na tabela e se houver o post, então faça
elseif (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
  ...
}
```

Por isso o `update` não ocorre, troque o `elseif` por `if`:

```
//Se houverem dados da tabela, então
if ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
  ...
} 
//Se houver o post, então
if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: agora estou com outro erro/bug..