# Update nao funciona na base de dados

Tags: php, html, mysql

Boas pessoal, [já tinha feito um topico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/60015/update-n%C3%A3o-funciona-na-base-de-dados) aqui sobre isto e resolveram logo, mas  depois reparei que ao arranjar este problema fiquei com outro. Aqui vai o código:

```
<?
error_reporting(0);
require('cdn/inc/header.php'); 

if(isset($_SESSION['user_data'])):
$user_level = $_SESSION['user_data']['level'];


switch($user_level):
case 1:
case 2: 
case 3: 
case 5:
case 8:
case 9:

$query = "SELECT * FROM testes WHERE ID = :ID";
$result = $db->prepare($query);
$result->execute(array(':ID' => $_REQUEST['ID']) );
if ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { 
?>


<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post"> 

  <input id="Title" type="text" name="Title" value="<?php echo $row['Title']; ?>" required />


 <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>" />
 <input type="Submit" name="Submit" value="Salvar alterações" />
</form>

<? 
 } 
 elseif (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
 $ID = $_POST['ID']; 

 $Title = $_POST['Title'];

  $queryupdate = "UPDATE testes SET Tile = :Title WHERE ID= :ID";   
 $q = $db->prepare($queryupdate);
 $q->execute(array(":Title" => $Title));
 header ('Location: edit.php');} 

 else {
 $stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM testes ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(Date, '%d-%m-%y') ASC, Title ASC);
 $stmt->execute();
 $data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);?>

 <div id="user-bar" style="background: #C16011;">
  <i>
   <a href="add.php">Adicionar</a>
  </i>
 </div>

 <br />
 <br />

 <?
 foreach($data as $index => $row) { 
 $className = $index % 2 == 0 ? "class" : "class-1" ?>

<form action="" name="Inser" method="post">
 <div class="selector">
  <input name="selector[]" class="selector" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>" />
 </div>

   <a href="edit.php?ID=<? echo $row['ID']; ?>"><? echo $row['Title']; ?></a>


   </div>
  </h6>
 </div>

<?
 }
 if(empty($data)){?>

 <div class="no-data">
  DATA/HORA: <b><?echo date("d-m-Y");?></b>/<b><? echo date("H:i");?></b>
 <br />
  SEM NADA
 </div>

<?}
else
{?>

 <div class="btn-padding">
  <div class="btn-group dropup pull-right">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Seleciona uma acção</button>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="caret"></span>
    <span class="sr-only"></span>
   </button>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
    <li><a href="" class="selectall-button" onClick="return false;">Selecionar tudo / Nao selecionar</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#" type="submit" class="delete-button"onclick="javascript:document.Insert.submit();">Eliminar</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
</form>


 <?
 }
 $edittable=$_POST['selector'];
 $N = count($edittable);
 for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++)
 {
 $result = $db->prepare("DELETE FROM testes WHERE ID= :ID");
 $result->bindParam(':ID', $edittable[$i]);
 $result->execute();
 header ('Location: edit.php'); 
 }
 } 
?>

 <br />
 <br />

 <center>
  <small>TESTE.</small>
 </center>


</body>
</html>

<?
break;
 endswitch;
 else:
 header( 'Location: ../ ');
 endif;
?>
```

Aqui está igual como eu abri o [outro tópico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/60015/update-n%C3%A3o-funciona-na-base-de-dados), ou seja, quando eu faço `submit` não faz update na base de dados, mas se eu mudar o `elseif` para `if`, quando vou para editar o post fica a lista que tenho na tabela por baixo da edição.

Há alguma maneira para resolver isso?

Answer (score 1):

Ao fazer o update informe os dois campos que estão nele, `title` e `ID`. Ao realizar testes comente as linhas de com `header()` assim a mensagem de erro é exibida e a página não é redirecionada.

```
 $queryupdate = "UPDATE testes SET Tile = :Title WHERE ID= :ID";   
 $q = $db->prepare($queryupdate);
 $q->execute(array(":Title" => $Title)); /// <------- está faltando o bind de :ID
```

Mude a última linha para:

```
 $q->execute(array(":Title" => $Title, ":ID" => $ID));
```

Comment: ja o fiz e o erro permanece, apenas da refresh a pagina mas nao faz update a nada

Comment: Qual erro? poderia colocar a mensagem

Comment: Nenhum erro, esta a checkar isso agora, apenas da refresh e nao aparece nenhuma mensagem ..

Comment: coloquei isto no topo: `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);` e mesmo assim nao me aparece mensagem de erro

Comment: @thecreator, talvez o problema seja essa linha `if(isset($_SESSION['user_data'])):` de um var_dum ou print_r em $_SESSION

Comment: `Array ( [loggedin] => 1 [username] => testuser1 [user_data] => Array ( [memberID] => 7 [username] => testuser1 [password] => $2y$10$t7q7XNa00.8ikOQ2lwZP7OF.1mlv4P9jlNvELuNWSSq0jacWIM.ou [email] => testuser1@asdas.com [level] => 1 [active] => Yes [avatar] => [resetToken] => [resetComplete] => No [color] => CE9715 ) ) `

Comment: eu resolvi colocando `if` em vez de `ifelse` e fechar o if depois do `submit`

Comment: agora tenho outra questão, pode ir ao chat?

Comment: @thecreator pode falar

Comment: por exemplo, eu tenho um 'a href' que da submit ao form, como meto ele a dar submit e a aparecer uma mensagem d confirmação e só se eu der ok é que ele acaba a accao?

Comment: @thecreator, precisa chamar uma função javascript no href. O que mostra essa mensagem é o `confirm()`